# vb.net how to launch Minecraft?

Tags: java, vb.net, process, minecraft, launch

Okay, I have a problem, I'm creating a launcher for Minecraft. My problem: I get this error messege, when I try launch Minecraft: `Error: Could not find or load main class net.minecraft.client.main.Main`

My code, I writted this, but not works:

The Detail of code:

**Logger as module, my program using this to write information to console.**

**JavaPaht as string, the Java path is stored in this.**

**GameLibraries as string too, the libraries stored in this.**

**MinMemAlloc as string, the minimal allocated memory for java.**

**MaxMemAlloc as string, the maximal allocated memory for java.**

**Root as string, this is the root directory of Minecraft.**

Here is the full sub to launch game:

```
Private Sub LaunchGame()
        If Not File.Exists(Root + "\versions\" + SelectedGameVersion + "\" + SelectedGameVersion + ".jar") Then
            MsgBox("File not found: " + SelectedGameVersion + ".jar")
        Else

            Logger.Write("Launching Game...")
            Logger.SetScrollDown()
            Dim Gamelibraries As String = Nothing
            For i = 0 To FileList.Count - 1
                Gamelibraries += FileList.Item(i) + ";" +
                Environment.NewLine()
            Next

            Logger.WriteWithJumpDown("Libraries loaded: " & Gamelibraries.ToString())
            Logger.SetScrollDown()
            Logger.Write("Building Process...")
            Logger.Write("Received data: ")
            Logger.SetScrollDown()
            Dim p As New Process()
            p.StartInfo.FileName = JavaPath
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = " -Xms" + MinMemAlloc + "M -Xmx" + MaxMemAlloc + "M " +
                "-Djava.library.path=" + Root + "\versions\" + SelectedGameVersion + "\" + SelectedGameVersion + "-natives -cp " +
                Gamelibraries.ToString() +
                Root + "\versions\" + SelectedGameVersion + "\" + SelectedGameVersion + ".jar " + mainClass +
                " --username=" + UserID +
                " --version " + SelectedGameVersion +
                " --gameDir " + Root +
                " --assetsDir " + Root + "\assets" +
                " --assetIndex " + assets +
                " --accessToken null" +
                " --userProperties {}" +
                " --userType mojang" +
                " --uuid (Default)"
            p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Root
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
            p.EnableRaisingEvents = True
            Application.DoEvents()
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
            AddHandler p.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf p_OutputDataReceived
            AddHandler p.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf p_OutputDataReceived
            p.Start()
            p.BeginErrorReadLine()
            p.BeginOutputReadLine()
            Logger.SetScrollDown()
            Button1.Text = "Play"
            Button1.Enabled = True
            Button2.Enabled = True
            Button3.Enabled = True
            Button4.Enabled = True
            Button5.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

And my program writing the output into my console, so I write here the output:

```
[14:34:41 INFO ] Libraries loaded: C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\java3d\vecmath\1.5.2\vecmath-1.5.2.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\net\sf\trove4j\trove4j\3.0.3\trove4j-3.0.3.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j-core-mojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\4.6\jopt-simple-4.6.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-20101023.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\com\paulscode\librarylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.0.15.Final\netty-all-4.0.15.Final.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\com\google\guava\guava\17.0\guava-17.0.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2\commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.9\commons-codec-1.9.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\com\google\code\gson\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\com\mojang\authlib\1.5.16\authlib-1.5.16.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\com\mojang\realms\1.5\realms-1.5.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-compress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.0-beta9\log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.0-beta9\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.9.1\lwjgl-2.9.1.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.1\lwjgl_util-2.9.1.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.1\lwjgl-platform-2.9.1-natives-windows.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\tv\twitch\twitch\6.5\twitch-6.5.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\tv\twitch\twitch-platform\6.5\twitch-platform-6.5-natives-windows-64.jar;
C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\libraries\tv\twitch\twitch-external-platform\4.5\twitch-external-platform-4.5-natives-windows-64.jar;

[14:34:41 INFO ] Building Process...
[14:34:41 INFO ] Received data: 
[14:34:41 INFO ] 
[14:34:41 INFO ] Error: Could not find or load main class net.minecraft.client.main.Main
[14:34:41 INFO ]
```

**Thanks for help!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the main class on the path after the jars are included "net.minecraft.client.main.Main" unless mainClass means that already, then I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for rely, but I already set the main class in my code: `Root + "\versions\" + SelectedGameVersion + "\" + SelectedGameVersion + ".jar " + mainClass +` the mainClass as string, the program stored the main class (`net.minecraft.client.main.Main`), so I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: So what full path does Root + "\versions\" + SelectedGameVersion + "\" + SelectedGameVersion + ".jar actually result in upon running your application? Apparently the jar exists or you'd get a message box, but it does not contain the actual class you are trying to run. Note that jar files are just zip files, you can open it up to see what is in there.

Comment: `Root + "\versions\" + SelectedGameVersion + "\" + SelectedGameVersion + ".jar ` = `C:\Users\ProGamer\AppData\Roaming\.elcplatform\versions\1.8.1\1.8.1.jar`

Comment: Yes, but the original launcher launching game with the original jar file, and my launche downloads the original jar file , so I don't understand the error. Thanks !

Comment: And what is inside this 1.8.1.jar / zip file? Is there a file /net/minecraft/client/main/Main.class ? If so then there is likely something silly wrong with your complicated process setup, such as a missing escaped quote somewhere. I'd see if you can somehow get the full process invocation as a String.